# Objective C - caller Object of a method

Tags: objective-c, function, call

I have a Utility class which contains a static method, which can be called from anywhere in the code. Inside the Utility method, is there a way to get a reference of the calling Object.
Eg:

```
//Utility class method
+ (void) doA {
       // something similar to _sender.doB
}
```

Comment: Pass it as a parameter.

Comment: change method to `doSomething:(id)sender`